# Is it possible to transfer free storage space from one hard drive to another?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Windows 7 and my `C://` drive has a total disk size of of 50GB. My `G://` and `F://` drives have much disk free on each drive with 50GB minimum available.

Due to all of the programs I install, my `C://` drive is almost full with only 4GB left.

Now , my question is how do I transfer that extra 50GB from the `G://` and `F://` drives in to the `C://` drive, so I get some more space?

After doing some searching on Google I found [this] blog post titled, “[Resize a Partition for Free in Windows 7, 8.x, 10, or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)”. Will this work?

**UPDATE**: Okay, nevertheless, looks like I will try this quite unsafe thing some other day along with a techie. Thanks for all your help everybody.

Comment: Have you tried to move documents, music and photos to the another drive to free up space on C:?

Comment: Actually , they are not documents ,all are program files on C:// , and I tried moving few programs from C to G , but that made them (programs) behave abnormally :(

Comment: Is this one physical disk with multiple partitions? Or multiple physical drives

Comment: Quite confusing what you said, but what I know is that F:// and G:// were pre-existing on my pc.

Comment: Right-click Computer, then choose Management, Disk management. There you can see how your partitions are divided over physical disks. Then update your question with that information: "Disk 0 contains partitions ..." etc.

Comment: You can't just move installed applications as they often set up registry entries that include the location they were installed to. You should be able to initially install applications to non-default (non-C:) drives without trouble though (any applications that don't support that are poorly written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since I asked this question, I have switched over to using MiniTool partition wizard as the tool for managing my partitions. I have used it on Windows 7 multiple times without any hiccups. I did take a backup before using it though.

Download link - https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one physical hard drive in your computer, then the drives you are seeing are *partitions* on that drive.

Windows 7 has the ability to re-size partitions; more info is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/).

While it is quite safe, ***I heartily exhort you to back up your files before trying this.***

Comment: Okay , so I have one physical hard drive in my PC . But nevertheless , looks like I will try this quite unsafe thing some other day along with a techie .

Answer (score 0):

If the G: and F: drives are actually different disks then you can't transfer free space around like that. If they are the same drive and just different partitions then you might be able to use a partition manager to resize the partitions to do what you want (but realize that this is an inherently dangerous task when the partitions involved contain data, tools should be able to do it safely but if things go wrong they can go very wrong).

The simpler alternative is, as @CharlieRB mentions in his comment, to try to move things that do not need to live on your C: drive to one of the other drives. Many/most applications can even be installed to a non-default drive.

Comment: Well , I don't know much , but I know that F:// and G:// were pre-existing on my pc.

Comment: Just found [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) ,will it be suitable ?

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm this link will help you to get to the application which will let you know which partitions are on which disks and see if you can "transfer" space from one to another. I would highly recommend to move files instead, tho, as resizing partitions is considered unsafe. (data loss risk)

Comment: Actually, you can use a partition (I believe even on a different physical disk) as a regular directory; they don't need to have a *drive letter* assigned. That may or may not be a workable approach.

Comment: That's a good thing if Windows can do that but it doesn't directly impact the current question as that would require moving the entirety of some large directory hierarchy which may or may not be possible and may or may not have a good candidate for doing that with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EaseUS Partition Master to do this firstly download and install it.Then open it and navigate to the drive (In easeus partition master) which is next to the 'C' drive.Then right click in the drive and select resize drive and reduce the physical size of the drive then press apply on the upper pane then select shut down after the process option.Then restrart PC.TWO restart may be necessary.Then the reduced unallocated space you can add to 'C' drive following the same procedure without any data loss.But be careful that only reduce the size from forward not from the end of the drive.ENJOY...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Ever since I asked this question, I have switched over to using MiniTool partition wizard as the tool for managing my partitions. I don't want to risk using a new tool. Thanks for the suggestion though! It's appreciated!

Comment: Ya...you should use the tool which you understand and trust.Whatever you feel easy and safe you should go for it...